# Access to RecipientsQueue of PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to access to RecipientsQueue from phpmailer but I'm having some problems, the phpmailer class have a `protected $RecipientsQueue = array();` so I try to make a class who extends from PHPMailer and then get the RecipientsQueue

This is my PHPMailerAdapter class

```
<?php

namespace IEmpresas\Lib;


use PHPMailer;

class PHPMailerAdapter extends PHPMailer
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRecipientsQueue()
    {
        return $this->RecipientsQueue;
    }
}
```

Also I have an abstract class with:

```
/** @var PHPMailerAdapter */
    protected $mailerAdapter;
```

And in one method inside this abstract class I try to do: `$this->mailerAdapter->getRecipientsQueue();` but `$this->mailerAdapter` is null

Someone can guide me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted doesn't look correct - you have `use PHPMailer;`, when it should be `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;` if you're using PHPMailer 6, so it's likely your parent class effectively doesn't exist, which is why you're getting `null`.

Comment: I'm using PHPMailer version 5.2.26 and if I click to PHPMailer it goes to the father class correctly. Maybe I don't understand what you want to say

Comment: If you're using the old version, you don't need that `use` statement at all since PHPMailer 5.2 doesn't use a namespace. I'd recommend you upgrade to 6.x anyway.

Comment: If I don't put the use statement I get the advice 'Undefined class PHPMailer' . Now I see I get an exception when do the '$this->mailer->getRecipientsQueue()' I get : 'Call to undefined method PHPMailer::getRecipientsQueue()'

Comment: Ok, I see why that is - but I would still update to 6.0. I would advise trying `var_dump($mailer)` to be absolutely sure that it contains what you expect.